# Run iMacros in Firefox from within PHP

Tags: php, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I have **iMacros for Firefox** and I am trying to automate iMacros execution using **PHP**.

My problem is that **I do not know how to catch the iMacros return code and response** once it is finished. This is because currently I run the macros this way and the response (if any) will belong to firefox.

```
exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=1.iim');
```

Any ideas on how to **catch the response**!?

Comment: Using the JavaScript Scripting Interface for Firefox (i.e. js-scripts instead of iim-macros) it’s possible to write the ‘iMacros’ return code into an external txt-file. Perhaps, that would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try with converting to batch file `runwithlog.bat`

```
@echo off
set logfile=C:\project\imacros.log
echo execute imacros.bat at %date% %time% >> %logfile%
imacros.bat -options oas >> %logfile%
```

with content of `imacros.bat` is

```
start "Firefox" "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" imacros://run/?m=1.iim
```

then your php code :

```
<?php
exec('c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\project\runwithlog.bat');
?>
```

but the scenario only give you logs of when it's execute and running

or

A little bit long way,  create url php form to submit your imacros error code / log code.